# I am getting an Error 1822 failed when trying to create MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try and run this query, I get an error:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint.

However, based on other posts, I have ensured the data types were matching. Can someone please help me out? The issue is with the last table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Client 
(
    client_id int NOT NULL,
    client_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    client_address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    client_city varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    client_prov varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    client_postal varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id),
    UNIQUE (client_name)
);
    
CREATE TABLE Programmer 
(
    prog_id decimal(5,0),
    prog_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    prog_office char(5) NOT NULL,
    prog_phone char(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (prog_id)
);
    
CREATE TABLE Project 
(
    project_id decimal(6,1),
    project_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    complete_date date ,
    total_cost decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
    client_id int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (project_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES Client (client_id),
    CHECK (complete_date > "2020-01-01"),
    CHECK(total_cost > 0)
);
    
CREATE TABLE Project_mm_Programmer 
(
    prog_id decimal(5,0),
    project_id decimal(6,1),
    hours_worked decimal(3,1), -- NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (prog_id) REFERENCES Programmer (prog_id) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Project (project_id),
    CHECK(hours_worked > 0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is on the creation of the last table. It references a PK for the bridging table. The foreign key uses Project ID PK but..
Your table Project doesn't have a primary key like the Programmer and Client Tables do

```sql
CREATE TABLE Client ( 
    client_id int NOT NULL,
    client_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    client_address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    client_city varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    client_prov varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    client_postal varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    primary key (client_id),
    unique (client_name) 
);

CREATE TABLE Programmer (
    prog_id decimal(5,0),
    prog_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    prog_office char(5) NOT NULL,
    prog_phone char(10) NOT NULL,
    primary key (prog_id)
);


CREATE TABLE Project (
    project_id decimal(6,1),
    project_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    complete_date datetime,
    total_cost decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
    client_id int NOT NULL,
    unique (project_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES Client (client_id),
    CHECK (complete_date >  '2020-01-01'),   -- may have to change back to double ticks
    CHECK(total_cost>0),
    primary key (project_id)   -- add this line for sure
);

CREATE TABLE Project_mm_Programmer (
    prog_id decimal(5,0),
    project_id decimal(6,1),
    hours_worked decimal(3,1), -- NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (prog_id) REFERENCES Programmer (prog_id) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Project (project_id),
    CHECK(hours_worked>0)
);
```